# How to connect to Oracle in C++?

Tags: c++, oracle

I tried to connect to Oracle using C++ but it is giving me error stating that `DBManger.h` not found. I have also tried using `occi.h` but got the same error of not found or No Such Directory.

I have installed Oracle 11g and it contains the OCI Liabraries also.

I located the specififc folders also where the OCI libraries are present . In my system they are at location `E:\app\user\product\11.1.0\db_1\OCI\lib\MSVC\vc8`.

I have also set the Path starting with Oracle home. But, still my program is not able to find the header files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated? I Googled a lot but found the same solution stating that locate the folder where the OCI libraries are available. I am posting my code below written in Visual Studio 2008:

I have written a very small script and just included the header files. Not even done the connectivity:

```
#include <occi.h> 
#include <iostream>
using namespace oracle::occi;
using namespace std; 

class DataBaseConnectionTest
{
public:
void test()
{
    cout<<"Hello from test"<<'\n';
}
};
void main()
{
DataBaseConnectionTest *dbc=new DataBaseConnectionTest();
dbc->test();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify your project properties, add the E:\app...vc8 directory name to the Addition include directories. It's under C++/General. No need to double every \ in that one.

You'll probably need a similar treatment for the OCI library file anyway. The include file is only half the puzzle, the other half is the LIB.

Comment: But that vc8 folder only contains .dlls.and .lib files there are no .h files ! only oraocci11.lib and oraocci11d.dlls are available.

Comment: Even after providing the complete path! its not working. VC8 folder only contains .dlls and .lib files such as oraocci11.lib and oraocci11d.dlls. there are only 8 files including manifest and .sym files.

Comment: Is there anything inder OCI\include?

Comment: yes! I got those files under include folder! i again used the complete path tried to compile ut noe it is giving me below error Error 1 fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'oratypes.h': No such file or directory e:\app\user\product\11.1.0\db_1\oci\include\oci.h 514  This oratypes.h is thhe file included in oci.h.

Comment: Then the simple solution won't work. Modify the project properties to list the ...\include directory. The oratypes.h is probably there, too, but it's included without path (obviously), so the compiler cannot find it.

Comment: I have located the folder in ProjectPropertire->configuration Proprties->Linker->Additional Library directory but still there is same problem!  i don't know why it is not finding the header files. But i will try until i get some solution.

Comment: Is there any different kind of settings that i need to do in my visual studio 2008. or please let me know if we can directly use the whole OCI directory in our project just by placing it in the same directory in Which our code resides.

Comment: Project properties\Config properties\C/C++\General\Additional Include directories. That's for #include to find .h files.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now my code is working fine and i tested it also. I used occi.h header file because i have used "using namespace oracle::occi" statement in my code. now i will look for connecting and retrieving data from tables! thank you very much once again. Please let me know if i am moving in the right direction.

Comment: You are moving in the right direction, but we're not here to provide a complete tutorial. If the answer was helpful, please accept it; if you stumble upon something else, ask another question. That's how SO works. By the way, this problem of yours was totally about Visual C++, not about Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/) as alternative to OCI. Then your code could be more portable. I used it many years ago, interfacing SqlServer, and was surprised by the clean design and the raw speed (way faster than MFC+ODBC...). Also, I had a problem and Sergei gave me immediate assistance.

Comment: I downloaded otlv4.h header file and provided the complete path in my program to locate that file. after downloading i got only one otlv4.h header file and nothing else. My code got compiled and now i am looking for another step i.e. connectivity. please let me know if iam moving in the right direction.

Comment: All the functionality is in that file. Now you must connect using a DSN to your database (use ODBC GUI interface to define one, and then use DSN=...,UID=...;PWD=... in your connection string) or Goggle for using DSN less connection (i.e. you pass driver=... in your connection string)